# Loading config from class in such a way that it behaves like a property

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I'm trying to create a yaml-driven config module for python that loads both from a flat yaml file, and optionally loads params from sys.argv. It also saves the loaded properties to a local variable (which is ugly, but it's still preferable to parsing the yaml file every time `config` is referenced).

I have this working, but the way I have to import it seems over-the-top, and not very pythonic. Is there a more elegant way to construct this so that:

- I can use a single import statement
- I can ensure that the config isn't loaded more times (throughout different modules where it's used) than absolutely necessary

Structure:

```
/app
    /__init__.py
    /__main__.py # calls __init__.py
    /config.yaml
    /applib
        /__init__.py
        /__config_loader.py
```

In the app's main `__init__.py`, I load config like so:

```
from applib.config_loader import Config; config = Config()
#                                          ^ ew!
```

In `config_loader.py`, I have:

```
import argparse
import yaml

class Config:
    _config = None

    @property
    def config(self):
        if self._config is not None:
            print('Using what we already loaded')
        return self._config or Config()

    def __init__(self):
        if self._config is None:
            print('Loading config')

            with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.yaml')) as yaml_config_file:
                self._config = yaml.load(yaml_config_file)

            parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'MyApp')
            parser.add_argument('--an_arg')
            args = parser.parse_args()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._config[name] or None
```

Certainly not the prettiest way to get this to work, and it seems like my failing to understand the old vs. new way of doing things in python is overcomplicating the situation.

I'd like to be able to load it like:

```
from applib.config_loader import config

print(config['an_arg'])
```

Comment: "but it's still preferable to parsing the yaml file every time config is referenced" why would you have to parse the yaml file every time `config` is referenced?

Comment: From what I tested, it looks like `__init__` is called every time `config` is referenced, and thus the yaml file is parsed each time. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just add the line `config = Config()` at the end of your applib.config file?  Then `from applib.config import config` will work just like you want.

Comment: BTW the variable `Config._config` is not initialized by the statement `self._config = [something]` in the constructor `Config.__init__`.  That will create a new *member* variable named "_config" for that instance, but won't affect the *class* variable named "_config".  The class variable won't get set unless you execute a statement `Config._config = [something]`.

Comment: Yep, @PaulCornelius you're totally right. At least I was right about overthinking it  Toss that in and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem is to put this line:

```
config = Config()
```

after the definition of class Config.  But there is an even simpler solution: about half the code in config_loader.py can be removed.  Like this:

```
import argparse
import yaml

class _Config:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Loading config')
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.yaml')) as yaml_config_file:
            self.config = yaml.load(yaml_config_file)
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'MyApp')
        parser.add_argument('--an_arg')
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self.config[name]
        except KeyError:
            return getattr(self.args, name)

config = _Config()
```

Your client code now does:

```
from config_loader import config
```

You access attributes in config in the usual way, config.xxx.  You don't need to mess around with singleton object behavior or class variables.  The underscore in front of _Config guarantees that the class constructor will be called only once, when the module is loaded.  The class can be accessed only through the variable named `config`.

I also fixed a second, un-discussed problem: you were not using the variable "args" in the Config constructor, and were therefore not actually doing anything with the output of the command line parser.  I made args into a member variable and modified the `__getattr__` function appropriately.

Comment: Fantastic! And great catch, I'd found that myself after implementing too.